# How to "return this" in inner method with Chaining Pattern in java

Tags: java, inner-classes, fluent, method-chaining

I want to make inner method with Fluent Programming (a.k.a. Chaining method)

```
class OuterSay {
    String sentence = "";
    public OuterSay sayHello() {
        class OtherLanguage {
            public OuterSay inEnglish() {
                sentence = "Hello!";
                return this; // Error :: "this" is not OtherLanguage.
            }
            // and there are lots of other language method like inGermany(), inJapanese() and so forth..
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Recently, I used chaining pattern to code easier than before. Please look at above example.

I want to make inner method (inEnglish() in sayHello() ) because, IDE will help me what can I select (in Eclipse Autocomplete). In that example, IDE recommend me what language can I choose.

But **the problem is that I cannot return 'OuterSay' class** from inEnglish() method by using "return this" as I learn Chaining method. Of course I know it doesn't work because 'this' object is not OuterSay class but OtherLanguage class. But I don't know how to solve it.

What should I do to use inner method with Fluent Programming? I want to return 'this', which is OuterSay class, in inner method. Please help me.

Comment: `return OuterSay.this;`